# XSLT stylesheet replaces self-closing tags with empty paired tags

Tags: xslt

I'm using XSLT to process my ASP.Net web.config file to insert some extra log4net configuration.  It's applied by the NANT standard task called `<style>`.  While it successfully inserts the new content, it turns the many self-closing tags into empty paired tags.  For example, a partial web.config looks like this before:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/.NetConfiguration/v2.0">
<configSections>
    <section name="log4net"
             type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net"/>
</configSections>
<appSettings>
    <add key="SomeKey" value="SomeValue"/>
</appSettings>
```

After applying the stylesheet, the `<section>` and `<add>` tags (and all other tags) are no longer self-closing:

```
<configuration xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/.NetConfiguration/v2.0">
    <configSections>
        <section name="log4net"
         type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net">
        </section>
    </configSections>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="SomeKey" value="SomeValue">
        </add>
    </appSettings>
```

My stylesheet looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- This stylesheet is applied to web.config files to insert log4net appender
filters that will prevent logging messages resulting from pages requested by
AIS monitoring systems. -->
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" 
    exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:preserve-space elements="configuration"/>
    <!-- Copy input to output, most of the time -->
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Within log4net <appender> elements, insert standard filters to
    exclude logging traffic resulting from AIS monitoring.  Any existing
    filters are preserved. -->
    <xsl:template match="/configuration/log4net/appender">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
            <xsl:comment
            > Filters inserted by build server during deployment </xsl:comment>
            <filter name="AIS monitor"
             type="log4net.Filter.PropertyFilter">
                <regexToMatch value="^35\.8\.113\.[0-9]+$"/>
                <key value="ClientIP"/>
                <acceptOnMatch value="false"/>
            </filter>
            <filter name="AIS load balancer"
             type="log4net.Filter.PropertyFilter">
                <regexToMatch value="^10\.160\.0\.[0-9]+$" />
                <key value="ClientIP"/>
                <acceptOnMatch value="false"/>
            </filter>
            <filter name="localhost" type="log4net.Filter.PropertyFilter">
                <stringToMatch value="127.0.0.1"/>
                <key value="ClientIP"/>
                <acceptOnMatch value="false"/>
            </filter>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Before using NANT to process the stylesheet, I tried MSBuild, using the MSBuild Extension Pack task `XmlTask`.  It preserved the self-closing tags, but would lose most of the line breaks, which made the file human-unreadable (though otherwise correct).  Using NANT fits in nicely with my build process, so I'd prefer to use it if I can.

It seems like I should be able to specify that I want to keep self-closing tags in the stylesheet, but I can't figure out how.

Comment: I don't know NANT but looking at your stylesheet you could try to remove the `indent="yes"` from `<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />` to see whether that prevents the problem with added white space in those `add` or `section` elements. I realize my suggestion will probably impair the readability of the newly inserted elements elsewhere in your stylesheet but as a first attempt to find out where the white space inside of `add` comes from you could try it.

Comment: I just tried it, and the tags are still paired.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Self-closing tags `<empty/>` and empty element with start and end tags `<empty></empty>` are semantically identical. Therefore XSLT processor can output whichever it sees best.

You could try to fool the processor by adding empty content in elements. In this case it can be done by modifying the identity template.

```
<!-- Define a dummy variable with empty content -->
<xsl:variable name="empty" select="''"/>

<!-- Copy input to output, most of the time -->
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
<!-- Insert empty content into copied element -->
        <xsl:value-of select="$empty"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Or you could restrict this to empty elements by keeping the original identity template and adding this:

```
<!-- Identity template for empty elements -->
<xsl:template match="*[not(node())]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
        <xsl:value-of select="$empty"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Functionality depends on the XSLT processor.

**Note:** A proper XML tool should make no difference between self-closing tags or empty elements with start and end tag. So if this syntax difference is really causing you problems, you should reconsider what methods or tools you use or how you use them.

---

#### Update

Crap. Somehow I kept on reading your question the opposite way you meant (probably means it's time for me to take a nap). So... the code above tries to convert self-closing tags to empty pairs, whereas you wanted the opposite `<tag></tag>` --> `<tag/>`. Sorry for the mismatch, let me try again.

In a comment you said:

> Before it was on a new line and indented to the same position as the opening tag.

From the viewpoint of the XML data model, this means that the node has only empty whitespace as child content. One way of trying to avoid copying these text nodes would be to provide an empty template for them. This could cause problems with mixed content, though.

```
<xsl:template match="text()[normalize-space() = '']"/>
```

Another possible solution would be that when we confront empty elements we create a new element with same name instead of copying it.

```
<xsl:template match="*[not(comment() | processing-instruction() | *)][normalize-space(text()) = '']">
    <xsl:element name="{name()}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
        <xsl:for-each select="@* | namespace::*">
            <xsl:copy/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

This template also copies (unused) namespace definitions in empty elements, which actually seems quite unnecessary. `<xsl:for-each>` is used instead of `<xsl:apply-templates>` only because `template match` doesn't allow the use of `namespace` axis. `<xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>` works too, if you don't want to preserve the extra namespace definitions.

But in the end, AFAIK all these are just processor specific workarounds. When XSLT 1.0 processor creates an empty element, can freely choose whether to use a self-closing tag or an empty pair. Someone please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: That looked promising, but it still produces paired tags. Now, however, the closing tag is on the same line as the opening tag.  Before it was on a new line and indented to the same position as the opening tag.  So I think we're in the ballpark.

Comment: @Carl Raymond: Sorry, I thought that you only wanted to convert self-closing tags to pairs. If you want to keep original indentation formatting on some elements, you could try adding those element names to preserve-space element `<xsl:preserve-space elements="configuration add section"/>`. You can also use `elements="*"` to match all element names.

Comment: I'm marking this as correct because it's pretty comprehensive, and points out that it really doesn't matter whether the tags are self-closing or paired.  I'm proceeding with paired tags.  It just seemed like it should be an easy thing to do.  Thanks to all.

Comment: Well I just discovered there's an MSBuild task called `Xslt` in MSBuild Community Tasks, which I'm already using in my build process.  I hadn't noticed it before.  It does it exactly right: my self-closing tags stay that way, and it doesn't mess up the formatting.  Wish I'd found that a while back.

Answer (score 5):

Just add comment in the element, it will not self close.

> <xsl:comment> </xsl:comment>

Comment: this would inject a <!-- --> node inside.

Comment: For XSLT1, that no have control about it, this is the solution! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Why not use

```
<xsl:output method="html" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Most XSLT processors will serialize an empty element in the output as `<x/>` rather than `<x></x>`. It's not clear to me which XSLT processor you are using, or why it isn't doing this, but it's perfectly within its rights - the two constructs are 100% equivalent and anyone consuming the XML properly won't care which form is used.

Comment: I expected to get self-closing tags, and I'm surprised I don't.  I'm looking at the source code for NANT's <style> task, and I see it's using .Net's XslTransform object.  The source for the XmlTask in MSBuild Extension Pack uses XslCompiledTransform.  So that accounts for the different behavior.