# How to prevent minimized empty xml tags using XQuery from SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, tags, xquery, minimized

I am generating XML from SQL Server 2005 using a `SELECT` statement with XQuery syntax.

Is there a way to generate end tags for empty elements? Basically the xml output generated from this sql statement feeds into a "legacy" c# xml parser that doesn't like minimized tag elements! Otherwise everything works fine.

```
select  
    -- (this generates empty xml element which throws out the parser)
    main.sub.query('schoolname').value('.','varchar(50)') "newparent/newchild/newschoolname"  
from
    @xml.nodes('/parent/child') AS main(sub)
for xml path(''), type)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use an XSLT processor to transform the empty tags to paired tags, or remove them as in the following questions:

- [XSLT stylesheet replaces self-closing tags with empty paired tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5032347/xslt-stylesheet-replaces-self-closing-tags-with-empty-paired-tags)
- [Removing empty tags from XML via XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6648679/removing-empty-tags-from-xml-via-xslt)

Comment: Is there any way inside SQL-Server to use a different XSLT processor? I think your answer does not work on SQL-Server.