# How to transform self closing tag xml into empty tags xml on WSO2 Integration

Tags: xml, wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I am working on a project where i need to have empty xml tags formatted as follows **`<xyz></xyz>`** instead of self-closing tags **`<xyz/>`**, although both are equal it seems client's implementation is faulty. It accepts the empty tag and rejects the self-closing tag.

I am using WSO2 Integrator, however it forces that all empty tags to be formatted as self-closing tags. Is there a way to reformat it as empty tags as explained?

Comment: Self closing tag is like <xyz/>, but not like </xyz>

Comment: According xml specification both variants are equal https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#dt-empty

Answer (score 0):

Try with XSLT mediator. These might work.

```
<!-- Define a dummy variable with empty content -->
<xsl:variable name="empty" select="''"/>

<!-- Copy input to output, most of the time -->
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
<!-- Insert empty content into copied element -->
        <xsl:value-of select="$empty"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

or

```
<!-- Identity template for empty elements -->
<xsl:template match="*[not(node())]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
        <xsl:value-of select="$empty"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5033301/805563

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work on WSO2 ...still overrides it and replaces it with self closing tags.